# Не запускается файл test.py

Tags: python, discord, discord-api

Я пишу бота для Discord, и у меня он просто не запускается, из за ошибки номер 2, такого файла не существует либо не существующая директории. Что делать?

```py
import discord 

class Myclient(discord.Client):

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'format(self.user))

    async def on_message(self, message):
        print('Message from {0.author}: {0.content}'.format(message)) 

client = MyClient()
client.run('ТУТ У МЕНЯ СТОИТ ТОКЕН')
```

Comment: Как вы запускаете код? И какое имя у файла с кодом?

Comment: Можете отправить структура проекта, команду, которую вы выполняете что бы попытаться запустить файл, и ошибку которую выдает питон.